# java google spreadsheet get cell color

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I'm using Google Sheets API v4 for get a spreadsheet (excel) from my google drive. Following this tutorial https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java i achieved my first goal which is to retrieve all the data as a Json into my standalone java  application.
It works well and i can save it well into my DB.
Now i'm also required to get the cell colors, and cell hints (if exist). But until now i've been struggling without any success on the web. I need to do it without javascript.
Following there is my code :
I get all the values into the array of array called values,but just the value of the cell is retrieved here, nor the background color, neither the cell hints.

```
        Sheets service = getSheetsService();    
        String spreadsheetId = "xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx";
        String range = "A1:ce604";

        service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId);

        ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId, range).execute(); 

        List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();

        spreedSheetService.stroreDatas(values);
```

Does anybody know if is it possible to do it ?

Answer (score -1):

You may use the [`getBackground()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackground) which returns the background color of the top-left cell in the range (i.e., `'#ffffff'`).

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var cell = sheet.getRange("B5");
Logger.log(cell.getBackground());
```

Or the [`getBackgrounds()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackgrounds) to return the background colors of the cells in the range (i.e., `'#ffffff'`).

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var range = sheet.getRange("B5:C6");
var bgColors = range.getBackgrounds();
for (var i in bgColors) {
  for (var j in bgColors[i]) {
    Logger.log(bgColors[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The initial request is for using the Remote Java API not local javascript